# What is the translation for French expression "fiche produit"

Tags: nouns, translation

In production sector we talk about "fiche produit" to designate the document defining a product. I would like to know what the English translation for that is.

Comment: Design document? Product specification? We may need a bit more information about what a *fiche produit* actually contains. And possibly what sort of "production sector" is meant.

Comment: Metallurgy. The "fiche produit" defines the details of a item produced (customer, history...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a short single-paged document describing a product for potential customers, a common term is "product sheet." There is also "data sheet" to describe specific mechanical/electrical/financial/etc characteristics of a product in greater depth (for eg a motor/electronic component/financial offering).